# Connecting to SQL Server Express 2012 via ODBC from a 32bit C++ App (and TCP/IP)

Tags: c++, sql-server

I have a 32bit app that I am trying to connect to SQL Server Express 2012 via ODBC. I have checked the server and the browser are running. I can connect via windows authentication using the Management Studio Tool. Using the Configuration manager I have started SQL Server Browser (SQL Server Agent is not able to start in Express). I have turned on Pipes and TCP/IP.

I have looked at connections strings .com and tried many combinations including:

```
"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; Server=MyComputer\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AdventureWorks; Trusted_Connection=yes;"
"Driver={SQL Server};Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AdventureWorks;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
```

Finally I created a DSN using odbcad32.exe (to avoid the architecture mismatch error) and that works fine. I can connect and execute queries. No luck

ADDED

A string that works:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; Server=INTELXEON\SQLEXPRESS; UID=Development;Trusted_Connection=Yes;WSID=INTELXEON;
```

ADDED

For TCP/IP connections:

```
Driver={SQL SERVER Native CLIENT 11.0};SERVER=22.22.22.22\SQLEXPRESS,22222;uid=sa;pwd=yourpassword;app=appname;wsid=INTELXEON
```

If that saved you hours of work, vote this question up.

Comment: Not to sound rude but is that exactly the same code as you were using or have you changed the computer name to a generic name? You've written "MyConputer" in the connection string instead of "MyComputer" :P

Comment: yes a generic name NOT the actual string